# Smooth point implies infinitely many rational points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.4425.pdf) article on strong approximation, and am coming across the following example of the hypersurface $X$ defined by $3x^3 + 4x^3 + 5z^3 = 0$.

The claim is that since any point on $X$ other than the origin is smooth, and since $X(\mathbb Z_p) \neq \emptyset$, $X(\mathbb Z_p)$ must be infinite.

My first question, is why this implies $X(\mathbb Z_p)$ is infinite.  And second, what is meant by smooth points on $X$?  Do we need to base change $X$ to $\mathbb Q$, or $\mathbb Q_p$, to talk about smoothness?

[image]

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/selmerexample.pdf

Comment: I don't think that link provides an answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

Any smooth $\Bbb Z_p$ variety is either empty or contains infinitely many points. This is a consequence of the implicit function theorem for $p$-adic analytic functions (see [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~yifei/Hensel_lemma.pdf) for an online source, although I originally learned of it from a paper of Serre I can't find at the moment...). The implicit function theorem gives an p-adic analytic diffeomorphism (and in particular, a bijection) between an open subset of $X(\Bbb Z_p)$ and $\Bbb Z_p^n$, so the former has infinitely many points.

Secondly, smoothness is defined intrinsically for schemes and does not require base-changing. See for instance [StacksProject on smoothness](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V4).

Comment: This answer contradict Faltings's theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't follow. The Falting's theorem I know deals with $\Bbb Q$-rational points on curves over $\Bbb Q$ and the question above deals with $\Bbb Z_p$-rational points on a surface defined over $\Bbb Z_p$, so I don't see where Falting's theorem would apply. Could you explain a little more, please?

Comment: Why doesn't your argument apply to rational points on a curve over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You're right, this is different. A correct reason is that there's a p-adic analytic implict function theorem, which gives an p-adic diffeomorphism (and in particular, a bijection) between an open subset of $X(\Bbb Z_p)$ and $\Bbb Z_p^n$, so the former has infinitely many points. Editing the answer...